# Kafka working inefficient (Consumer Python)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a problem with apache kafka and the problem is ;

When I send message from my backend(spring-boot) to my topic, python client does not receive it immediately moreover it is not receive at all , it is not like this always sometime it receive it sometimes is not. I am using KafkaConsumer library in Python code.

> main.py

```
while True:
    messages = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=1000)

    print(f"There is no message  : {messages}")

    for topic_partition, message_list in messages.items():
        for message in message_list:
            if message is None:
                continue
            else:
                value = message.value.decode('utf-8')  # Eğer mesaj utf-8 kodlaması kullanıyorsa
                kafka_arr = value.split(',')
                value = kafka_arr[0]
                stationCode = kafka_arr[1]
                print(stationCode + ' stationCode comes from api' + getStation + ' comes from current directory')

                if stationCode == getStation:
                    print('Match - Station')
                    switch_case(value)
                else:
                    continue`
```

> Spring boot ;

```
private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "pas-advance-message";

@Autowired
public KafkaProducerService(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_NAME, message);
```

Also I checked kafka from my CLI when I run

`./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic pas-advance-message` I can see my messages from terminal.

Any configuration I need to do in kafka properties(Currently they are default) ?

I read somewhere place that the problem causing from group-id.
Do I need to clear group id in order to kafka work more efficiently ?

Comment: Are you flushing your producer when sending messages? Your consumer code is fine, assuming getStation is defined somewhere

Comment: I see no flush after your send statement... Sending never sends immediately

Comment: I did what officials tutorial shows me

Comment: Okay? It'll send to a buffer, then eventually make a network request... If you expect data immediately, you're required to flush the producer

Comment: Okay, thanks for notify. I will search this in spring

Comment: It's just `kafkaTemplate.flush()`. You can also use `send(...).get()` to block on the Future object returned from send function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating new group-id in Kafka